# Questions about fio output interpretation

Tags: benchmarking

I'd like to ask your help to interpret the test result of fit benchmark.
I tested it for AWS EBS volume benchmark.
It writes 16 files, 1G for each, as 16k per request.
I think the total write io size should be 1024MBx16=16384MB, but the output said it is 575184KB.
Could you let me know how this result can come out?
(The target directory /mnt/test is combined by two volumes as RAID 0.)

The output is like below:

```
$ sudo fio --directory=/mnt/test --name fio_rw_test --direct=1 --rw=randwrite --bs=16k --size=1G --numjobs=16 --time_based --runtime=180 -group_reporting -norandommap
fio_rw_test: (g=0): rw=randwrite, bs=16K-16K/16K-16K/16K-16K, ioengine=psync, iodepth=1
...
fio-2.14
Starting 16 processes
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
fio_rw_test: Laying out IO file(s) (1 file(s) / 1024MB)
Jobs: 14 (f=14): [w(2),_(1),w(7),_(1),w(5)] [33.5% done] [0KB/3312KB/0KB /s] [0/207/0 iops] [eta 05m:59s]
fio_rw_test: (groupid=0, jobs=16): err= 0: pid=20460: Thu Jan 21 15:41:41 2021
  write: io=575184KB, bw=3192.8KB/s, iops=199, runt=180152msec
    clat (usec): min=545, max=201975, avg=80143.65, stdev=76991.72
     lat (usec): min=546, max=201976, avg=80144.34, stdev=76991.75
    clat percentiles (usec):
     |  1.00th=[  676],  5.00th=[  692], 10.00th=[  716], 20.00th=[  764],
     | 30.00th=[  804], 40.00th=[  860], 50.00th=[80384], 60.00th=[158720],
     | 70.00th=[158720], 80.00th=[160768], 90.00th=[160768], 95.00th=[160768],
     | 99.00th=[160768], 99.50th=[160768], 99.90th=[168960], 99.95th=[171008],
     | 99.99th=[199680]
    lat (usec) : 750=18.07%, 1000=25.65%
    lat (msec) : 2=1.89%, 4=0.09%, 10=0.40%, 20=0.56%, 50=1.59%
    lat (msec) : 100=2.75%, 250=48.99%
  cpu          : usr=0.01%, sys=0.05%, ctx=36282, majf=0, minf=147
  IO depths    : 1=100.0%, 2=0.0%, 4=0.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     submit    : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     complete  : 0=0.0%, 4=100.0%, 8=0.0%, 16=0.0%, 32=0.0%, 64=0.0%, >=64=0.0%
     issued    : total=r=0/w=35949/d=0, short=r=0/w=0/d=0, drop=r=0/w=0/d=0
     latency   : target=0, window=0, percentile=100.00%, depth=1
Run status group 0 (all jobs):
  **WRITE: io=575184KB, aggrb=3192KB/s, minb=3192KB/s, maxb=3192KB/s, mint=180152msec, maxt=180152msec**
Disk stats (read/write):
    md1: ios=0/36040, merge=0/0, ticks=0/0, in_queue=0, util=0.00%, aggrios=0/18019, 
aggrmerge=0/1, aggrticks=0/1442112, aggrin_queue=1350932, aggrutil=91.25%
  nvme9n1: ios=0/17898, merge=0/1, ticks=0/368388, in_queue=327596, util=16.08%
  nvme8n1: ios=0/18140, merge=0/1, ticks=0/2515836, in_queue=2374268, util=91.25%
```

Comment: Hi, please consider reformating your code

Comment: Hello there, this doesn't seem like a programming question... Due to this you are more likely to get a good response on one of the other sites like https://serverfault.com/ . If you do move it, could you post a comment here saying where it went and also apply majkrzak's suggestion to improve the formatting? Thanks!